# Rails has_many :through with uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I asked this question differently, but deleted it to attempt more clarity.

I have an Article model.   It has_many contacts, through: :article_contacts.

I have a Contact model.   It has_many articles, through: :article_contacts.

What I need is each Contact object to be unique, but be able to be associated with different articles.    My last question led to people showing me how to display only unique contacts, or to validate the join model, but that's not what I need.

I need, for example, tables like the following:

```
Article
id: 1, name: "Whatever", content: "Whatever"
id: 2, name: "Again, whatever", content: "Whateva"

Contact 
id: 1, email: "email@email.com"
id: 2, email: "secondemail@email.com"

ArticleContact
id: 1, article_id: 1, contact_id: 1
id: 2, article_id: 1, contact_id: 2
id: 3, article_id: 2, contact_id: 1
```

So, when I build the association in my Article controller in the new action and I call @article.save in the create action, I get an insert of the new article, an insert of the contact and an insert of the article_relationship.   Great.

BUT, on Article 2, if I add the same email to the contact form, I do not want to create another Contact with the same email.   But I do want (as you see with the third ID in ArticleContact above) to create.   But each call to @article.save does it.   I've tried first_or_initialize and << into the collection, but it always creates multiple times and if I have a validation, it means I can't create the ArticleContact relationship because contact is unique.

I may eventually have a drop down with contacts, but I suspect that will be long, so I'd rather simply enter an email into a form and have the code check that it is unique and if so, just create the join relationship using the existing ID.

This must be easier than I am conceiving, but I can't find a single article that demonstrates this anywhere.

Updated with code per request, though, again, I don't have the code to only create a unique contact and associate the relationship with an existing one.   That's what I'm missing so this code will only show you what I already know works and not how to get to what I want :).

articlecontroller:

```
def new
  @article = @business.articles.build
  authorize @business
  @article.attachments.build
  @article.contacts.build
end

def create
  @article = @business.articles.new(article_params)
  authorize @business

  respond_to do |format|
    if @article.save
      format.html { redirect_to business_article_path(@business, @article), notice: "Knowledge created." }
    else
      format.html { render 'new' }
    end
  end

end
```

Models have the standard has_many :thruogh and belongs to.  I can show it, but they are the right way.   View is just a standard simple_form building the contact:

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :contacts, class: "form-inline" do |contact| %>
    <%= contact.input :first_name, label: "Contact First Name" %>
    <%= contact.input :last_name, label: "Contact Last Name" %>
    <%= contact.input :email, label: "Contact Email" %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Adding your controller, models and views code would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: I can, but these are extremely boiler plate.   I suspect the code I have does exactly what it is supposed to, i.e. build an association and on save, save the contact and the association.   I need it to be more complex and don't know how, but I'll put the boiler plate there :).

Comment: How are you assigning the `contact` to the `article` in the `articles_controller`?

Comment: In the new action I have @article.contacts.build set.

Comment: Why are you using a M:N relationship? Sound like, from your description, this should be 1:M?

Comment: Conceptually you are probably right.  My view was a single contact, unique in nature, like, say ME, can be a contact on zero, one or a million different articles.   And an article can have a million different contacts, but only one me.   So I thought has_many was right.   But maybe I'm thinking about it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You should enforce uniqueness, just in case:

```
# contact.rb
class Contact
  ...
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  ...
end
```

But in your controller you could do:

```
# articles_controller.rb
def create
  ...
  # we can rely on it's uniqueness
  contacts << Contact.find_or_create_by(email: param[:email)
  ...
end
```

Or whatever best fits your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply.   I do not want to enforce uniqueness on the form submission.   I know people will submit the same e-mail more than once.   If I validate on :email, which I've tried, I just get the standard form error stating the e-mail is already taken.   I know.   I need it to accept a duplicate on form submission, but then on create only add that param.   Your create looks right.   I've tried that, but it adds twice because @article.save saves it first.

Comment: So, I had to delete contacts_attributes from the form submission so that whitelisted_params = article_params, then delete from whitelisted params.   That allowed me to use this to build the contact separately and keep it unique.   I will confirm tomorrow but so far this is the only way I could keep @article.save from saving a contact.

Answer (score 1):

give your ArticleContact a validation with a scope.

```
validates :article_id, unique {scope: :contact_id}
```

this will prevent you from having ArticleContacts that are exactly the same.

when you create a contact, try:

```
contact = Contact.where(email: "e@mail.com:").first_or_create
```

in contact.rb

```
validates :email, uniqueness: true
```

Comment: That would work and I did try that, but the @article.save actually inserts the contact for me.   I'm not being given a chance to build it on the side.  That's my confusion.

Comment: personally, I would do this instead of building the contact before for that very reason. Create it on your own inside if @article.save and get rid of the build. should work.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this in the create method

```
verified_contacts = []

@article.contacts.each do |contact|
  existing_contact = Contact.find_by(email: contact.email)
  verified_contacts << (existing_contact || contact)
end

@article.contacts = verified_contacts
```